# Flutter + Dart : my class stop after i get the data from firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I do not know what happened but after the line where I get my data from firebase the class stops

```
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(user.id).get();
```

i tried to print something after that line but it won't run, no idea why...

i want my class to redirected the user to create an account

```
  createUserInFireStore() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(user.id).get();

if (!doc.exists) {
  final username = await Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

  userRef.document(user.id).setData({
    'id': user.id,
    'username': username,
    'photoURL': user.photoUrl,
    'email': user.email,
    'displayName': user.displayName,
    'bio': '',
    'timeStamp': timeStamp,
  });
}}
```

but everything stops after the lined I mentioned

the console show this

```
E/flutter (26482): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null, null)
```

Comment: looks like you did not properly setup firebase, see the documentation on the cloud_firestore package: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#setup

Answer (score 0):

in your 'CreateUserinFireStore' function, change the code inside the If condition to following,

```
 if (!doc.exists) {
      await userRef.document(user.id).setData({
        "id": user.id,
        "userNAme": userName,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timeStamp": timestamp
      });
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (conetext) => CreateAccount()));
 }
```

I think this link will help you
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Future `userRef.document(user.id).get()` just never returns, try a timeout:

```dart
final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(user.id).get().timeout(Duration(seconds:5));
```

if you get a timeout error, check the network connection, or if anything else is blocking your request to firebase.

Comment: i tried that, nothing happened, it seems any code after that line won't work

Comment: did you try printing something immediately before that line? because, this should either throw an error or continue after at most 5 seconds...

Comment: yes i did print something.. before the line is worked, after the line, it won't

Comment: your question was edited in the meantime to include an error, that the line throws, instead of describing the problem without an error.
check my comment under your question, could be a problem with your setup of cloud_firestore.